# Check Dropbox folder exists using SharpBox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, sharpbox

I'm uploading a file to Dropbox using SharpBox. It works fine however I'm also creating a folder on Dropbox to upload the file to. I can create the folder okay but I want to check first if the folder exists before I create it.
I can't seem to find a way to do this having looked everywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to create the folder. Folders will be implicitly created in Dropbox, so you can just upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/folder") != null) {
  // donot create folder
}
else {
 // create folder
}
```